# Obtain the Complement of a Scope Generated by AASM Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, aasm

This question is really intended to be answered by *AASM* gem developers.

I'm using the *AASM* gem in my rails app models (**Mongoid**). I know you automatically generate scopes for every defined state. For instance, having this...

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include AASM

  field :aasm_state

  aasm do
    state :pending, :initial => true
    state :received

    event :receive do
      transitions :from => :pending, :to => :received
    end
  end
end
```

...would allow me to do: *Order.pending* and *Order.received*.

My question is very simple, do you also generate scopes to get the complement of a given state?. Something like: *Order.not_pending* to get the *Orders* that have a status different than *'pending'*?.

I know it is pretty easy to build my own scope to obtain that, like this...

```
scope :not_pending, ->{ ne(aasm_state: "pending") }
```

...but I wanna make sure that you don't define it, because if you do, I'd rather use your scope than my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *AASM* doesn't provide the contrary scopes. We have thought about that, but finally decided against, in order not to burden the scope space more than necessary.